# Bespoke Development or Leverage SharePoint With Web Parts etc?

Tags: sharepoint, k2

We are currently in the process of drawing up a solution for an existing client, creating a number of eServices. The client currently have MOSS 2007. The proposed solution is to use MOSS as the launching pad for the eServices…

The requirement involves drawing up several online forms which provide registration facilities as well as facilitating a workflow of some sort. I have been told that the proposed solution requires complex web forms.

Most are complex forms with parent child details that have multiple windows. The proposed solution is to do some bespoke development, developing ASP .NET forms. These forms would be deployed under the _layouts folder of the current MOSS portal, inheriting the master page design on the current site.

I have been told that this approach make development and deployment more simple, as well has having ‘complete integration’ with MOSS.

My questions are:

1. Is this the best way to leverage SharePoint – it seems like the proposed solution is not leveraging MOSS at all..! I thought perhaps utilizing Web Parts would be better, but I have been told that this is more complex and developing more smarter intuitive UI is more difficult. Is this really the case? If not, what should be the recommended approach?
2. We will be utilizing Ultimus as the workflow engine. However, I have been recommended K2 Workflows. Anyone used both/have any opinions on either?

Many thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If they have MOSS 2007 Enterprise, you might consider if web rendered InfoPath forms can meet your needs for "complex web forms".  When it comes down to it, probably all of these technologies can meet the neeed it is just a matter of what skill sets you and your customer have and how that will facilitate keeping this solution up to date.

Comment: I thought InfoPath forms were quite restrictive and you could not make intuitive UI - is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Asim, what they propose is a possible solution. They can however provide the same functionality by making use of webparts. With the details you are giving us that isn't really possible to decide which option would be easier. I used both approaches in the same project depending on the requirements of each functionality.

I can understand that it doesn't seem like they are leveraging MOSS, but they actually are building pages within the context of MOSS.

I haven't really heard about Ultimus, I did use K2 in a proof of concept and I was quite happy with it. Then again, choosing the right workflow solution depends on your requirements.